# Why is bash failing to create a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin?

Tags: bash, terminal, sublimetext3

Attempting to create a symbolic link for the subl command so that I can open flies in Sublime Test 3 from the terminal. However, it fails to find the /usr/local/bin directory, even though it is in my path.

```
 $ ln -s /D/ProgramsD/SublimeText3/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
 ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/subl': No such file or directory
```

Comment: What's the output of `ls -ld /usr/local/bin` ?

Comment: $ ls -ld /usr/local/bin/
    ls: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/': No such file or directory

Comment: Can you perform `ls -ld /usr/local`? as paste the output?

Comment: ls: cannot access '/usr/local': No such file or directory

Comment: And finally `ls -ld /usr`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/subl': No such file or directory

This error can happen when one of the parent directories of `/usr/local/bin/subl` don't exist.

Create them with:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
```

> However, it fails to find the `/usr/local/bin` directory, even though it is in my path.

As the output of `ls -ld /usr/local/bin` reveals,
indeed there is no such directory.
The fact that the directory is on your `PATH` is irrelevant,
because being on the `PATH` doesn't imply that a directory actually exists.
In your example it doesn't exist, you need to create it.